# SharedPrefs, how to save the state of two toggle buttons?

Tags: android

I am making a project in which i am using two toggle buttons and i have to save there state so that it can work in background as per it is saved or not. I am able to save the state of first togglebutton but not able to save the state of second togglebutton and the second one can also start and stop service as per . So can anyone tell what must i do so that i can save the state of togglebuttons

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public ToggleButton led1, led2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    led1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleButton1);
    led2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleButton2);


            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.zapisywaniedanychtogglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE);
            led1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));

            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.zapisywaniedanychtogglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE);
            led2.setChecked(sharedPrefs1.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));

}


public void clickHendler(View v) throws InterruptedException {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.toogleButton1:
            if (led1.isChecked())
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
        break;

        case R.id.toogleButton2:
            if (led2.isChecked())
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.zapisywaniedanychtogglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.zapisywaniedanychtogglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use the same key to store values for both toggle button. Do it like this :

```
public ToggleButton led1, led2;
public SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 led1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleButton1);
 led2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleButton2);


 sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.peter.zapisywaniedanychtogglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE);
 led1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("Button_one_value", true));
 led2.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("Button_two_value", true));

}


public void clickHendler(View v) throws InterruptedException {

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

 switch (v.getId()) {

  case R.id.toogleButton1:
   if (led1.isChecked()) {
    editor.putBoolean("Button_one_value", true);
   } else {
    editor.putBoolean("Button_one_value", false);
   }
   editor.commit();
   break;

  case R.id.toogleButton2:
   if (led2.isChecked()) {
    editor.putBoolean("Button_two_value", true);
   } else {
    editor.putBoolean("Button_two_value", false);
   }
   editor.commit();
   break;
 }
}
```